# Python Idle closes when I scroll

Tags: python, crash, python-idle

Whenever I open Python IDLE, I have to use the little bar on the right side to keep from closing. At first, I thought IDLE kept crashing, but now I see that scrolling is a trigger for closing. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Are you using IDLE on a MacOS? maybe related to this bug? [IDLE: on macOS, scroll slider 'sticks' at bottom of file](https://bugs.python.org/issue34047)

Comment: Please add the version of python, the OS, how you installed python, and what version of tcl/tk (visible on Help => About IDLE).  And be much more specific about exactly what you do and what you see.  My best guess is that you are using  Mac, but there are still two possible problems.  And I have not seen 'crash on scrolling' reports before.

Comment: Yes. I am using IDLE on MacOs. Newest version. Downloaded it from the website. When I scroll, the app closes instantly, showing nothing.

Comment: The 3.7.1 and 3.6.7 release candidates came out about last Wednesday with multiple fixes and a slightly upgraded tcl/tk.  Please give them a try and report with more details if crashing continues.